# No match for 'operator>>'

Tags: c++

I can't figure out why it says this. I am new as you can probably tell... here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std
int main() {
    if (cin >> "hi"
        cout << "hello"

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. When asking a question with a code error, it's good to explain what you want to do and include any error messages in your question so we can help you fix the problem. At the moment I can't tell what you want the code to do. `cin >> "hi"` doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I feel so proud of actually [improving](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28522086/revisions) this question

Answer (score 3):

"The thing you were using" (read: your compiler) wanted you to end your `using namespace std` statement with a semicolon, not to dump one at the start of a function definition.

Your code has a number of extreme and baffling syntax errors, to the extent that it's not even clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Below is a hint to get you started but, from now on, I *strongly* recommend that you read [a good, peer-reviewed C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and *learn the language* before asking any further questions about nonsense code!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string input;
    getline(cin, input);

    if (input == "hi") {
       cout << "hello" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have been reading a book from 1995 that I got from my school library and got this compiler about 30 minutes ago. I'm not sure why I called it "the thing", my brain must have gone dead right then. I don't have money to spend on a book, so whatever I guess.

Comment: You should add the alternate form that will be seen when starting, using character arrays and `cin`.

Comment: @David: No, absolutely not, because that form _shouldn't_ be seen when starting out.

Comment: I've never seen a book not start out that way. They all start with the basics.

Comment: @David: Character arrays are not "the basics"; `std::string` is. Fumbling about with manual memory management and manually-bounded arrays is advanced. Unfortunately, bad books start with the advanced stuff pretending that it's the basics; however, [there are good books too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)!